# How to ignore properties of a specific type when using Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Let's suppose that I have two types:

```
class Type1
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

class Type2
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public TypeToIgnore Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map between these two types, but ignoring all the properties that have a `TypeToIgnore`. This is because I am iterating through all of them using reflection and make some custom mappings on them.

Within a class which derives from `Profile`, I could add an `Ignore` for each member that I don't want to be mapped, like this:

```
CreateMap<Type2, Type1>().ForMember(x => x.Prop3, y => y.Ignore());
```

Or I could use the `IgnoreMapAttribute` on the properties to be ignored, but considering that on the production code, I have plenty of them, is there a much easier way to ignore some specific types at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ShouldMapProperty` in your config:

```
 cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.PropertyType != typeof(string);
```

Official docs on this [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html?highlight=shouldmapproperty). Original [feature request](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/566) by yours truly.

Comment: This really does what I was looking for, that's why I am marking it as an answer, but I would still have liked it not to throw an exception when calling `cfg.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`

Comment: Honestly, that should not happen. Can you post another Question regarding that?

Comment: Yes, I will and I will come back with another comment here to let you know that I did, but right now I am a little bit busy, sorry :)

Comment: I just opened [another thread on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791850/strange-behavior-of-automapper-when-property-type-is-ignored). Thanks a lot for your help!