# Strange behavior of Automapper when property type is ignored

Tags: c#, automapper

After I saw [how to ignore a property type with Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771491/how-to-ignore-properties-of-a-specific-type-when-using-automapper/54772071?noredirect=1#comment96356376_54772071), I have tried it in a test project. It turns out that the property of a specific type is ignored properly, but when invoking `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` an exception is thrown, specifying that unmapped members were found. I can understand the reasoning of this exception, since the members of the type which should be ignored are not mapped, but what I am wondering is if this exceptions should be thrown in the context where I removed a mapping on purpose.

For the given code:

```
class Type1
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

class Type2
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public TypeToIgnore Prop3 { get; set; }
}

class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        ShouldMapProperty = p => p.PropertyType != typeof(TypeToIgnore);
        CreateMap<Type2, Type1>();
    }
}

//...

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile()));
config.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); //this throws AutoMapperConfigurationException
```

Wouldn't it be the correct behavior of Automapper to ignore the members and not throw an exception when verifying the validity of the configuration, as in the case of ignoring the property itself?

```
CreateMap<Type2, Type1>().ForMember(x => x.Prop3, y => y.Ignore());
```

Comment: Its only going to validate the destination as noted by @ZorgoZ Try reversing your CreateMap types then call ReverseMap: `CreateMap<Type1, Type2>().ReverseMap();` Should still allow mapping from Type2 to Type1.

Comment: @mxmissile thanks for your reply, I can see from the answer given by ZorgoZ that I assumed that the Automapper API will work in a different way than it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper maps from source to destination. As far as I know by default fields present in source but missing in the destination type are ignored. What you have to explicitly handle are the fields missing in the source, but present in the destination type. In your case `TypeToIgnore` is in the source. Thus by ignoring that type, you have no source counterpart of `Prop3` in the destination.

As an illustration, this will not throw exception:

```
ShouldMapProperty = p => p.PropertyType != typeof(TypeToIgnore);
CreateMap<Type1, Type2>();
```

Neither will this:

```
public class TypeToIgnore { }

void Main()
{

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile()));
    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); // won't throw
}

class Type1
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop3 { get; set; } // <- because bool is ignored, you could simply delete this row
}

class Type2
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public TypeToIgnore Prop3 { get; set; }
    public long Prop4 { get; set; }
    public double Prop5 { get; set; }
}

class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        ShouldMapProperty = p => p.PropertyType != typeof(bool);
        CreateMap<Type2, Type1>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see what you are saying and I don't doubt it, but I want to be mapping from `Type2` to `Type1` and to ignore only the properties with the `TypeToIgnore`. So in this case, the `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` will throw, because the `Prop3` will not have any mapping. What I am asking is: Is it normal for it to throw, since I really want to ignore that type? I guess that the answer to this question is that yes, it is normal for `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` to throw,as it doesn't fit the cases you have added into your answer.

Comment: @meJustAndrew Yes, it is normal. You are ignoring something from the source but you are not handling its counterpart in the destination. You have to tell AutoMapper what to do with the properties from the destination that are not matched from the source. Right now you are simply omitting one property from the source. Just try it: remove `public TypeToIgnore Prop3` altogether. You will get the same exception.